# How would I go back to a certain line Visual Basic 2013?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, repeat

I am currently using visual basic to create a project and am stuck on a certain point...
I am trying to get back to a certain point once the selected operation was completed.
I would like to repeat the Button1_Click sub if that's possible.
Heres my code so far.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Button1.Text = ("Transfer")
    TextBox1.Text = ("This program only allows the use of one application at a time in order to prevent corrupt files etc.")
    CheckBox1.Show()
    CheckBox2.Show()
    CheckBox3.Show()
    CheckBox4.Show()
    If CheckBox1.Checked Then
        CheckBox2.Enabled = False
        CheckBox3.Enabled = False
        CheckBox4.Enabled = False
        TextBox2.Show()
        TextBox2.Text = ("Completed without any faults : If error occurs resort to readme in download file.")
        Button1.Text = ("Quit")
    End If
    If CheckBox2.Checked Then
        CheckBox1.Enabled = False
        CheckBox3.Enabled = False
        CheckBox4.Enabled = False
        TextBox2.Show()
        TextBox2.Text = ("Completed without any faults : If error occurs resort to readme in download file.")
        Button1.Text = ("Quit")
    End If
    If CheckBox3.Checked Then
        CheckBox1.Enabled = False
        CheckBox2.Enabled = False
        CheckBox4.Enabled = False
        TextBox2.Show()
        TextBox2.Text = ("Completed without any faults : If error occurs resort to readme in download file.")
        Button1.Text = ("Quit")
    End If
    If CheckBox4.Checked Then
        CheckBox2.Enabled = False
        CheckBox3.Enabled = False
        CheckBox1.Enabled = False
        TextBox2.Show()
        TextBox2.Text = ("Completed without any faults : If error occurs resort to readme in download file.")
        Button1.Text = ("Quit")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: put the body of that method into another method then call that one?

Comment: If you're asking for how to use a `goto` command, then please stop asking for the 90's!  Look at implementing methods (as already suggested by Ric) and calling that when required

Comment: The `Button1_Click` method should only be used to respond to the user clicking `Button1`. If you need the code to be callable from other places, move it into it's own method, and then call that method from `Button1_Click` and any where else you need to call it. Event handlers are specifically designed for *responding to events*, which are typically user actions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Don't.

You've already implemented way too much functionality in that click handler, stop right there!

---

#### Extract Methods

You need to refactor a little bit here - *extract a method* for this part:

> ```
> TextBox2.Show()
> TextBox2.Text = ("Completed without any faults : If error occurs resort to readme in download file.")
> Button1.Text = ("Quit")
> ```

And then replace all copies of that snippet with a method call.

Then extract another method for each chunk you have there - and **name them**.

Consider renaming your controls/buttons as well - and thank yourself later :)

When you're done, your click handler should read like a high-level summary of what's happening, instead of like a monolithic script written in 1997 - because that's what your execution flow feels like right now.

Write a method for every **single thing** you want your code to do, and then call these methods. Simple!

---

If your code does what it's supposed to be doing (i.e. works as intended), and just looks messy, confusing and inefficient, consider asking on [**Code Review**](http://www.codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) next time!